# JetpackCompose LazyList extension function stale data

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make without paging lib load more functionality with JetpackCompose LazyColumn. All works fine except I am sending from parent isLoading value that is coming from ViewModel. But in my extension function this value never change. Any advice? Here is my code:

TileListView

```
@Composable
fun LazyListState.OnBottomReached(
    onEndReachedThreshold : Int = 0,
    onLoadMore : suspend () -> Unit,
    isLoading: Boolean = false
) {
    require(onEndReachedThreshold >= 0) { "buffer cannot be negative, but was $onEndReachedThreshold" }

    // Is Loading does not update from parent
    val shouldLoadMore = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val lastVisibleItem = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()
                ?:
                return@derivedStateOf true
            lastVisibleItem.index >=  layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 1 - onEndReachedThreshold
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(shouldLoadMore){
        snapshotFlow { shouldLoadMore.value}
            .collect { if (it) {
                onLoadMore()

            } }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TileListView(tiles: List<Tile>,
                 loadMore: suspend () -> Unit,
                 isLoading: Boolean,
                 onEndReachedThreshold: Int = 0,) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val tileViewModel: TileViewModel = hiltViewModel()

    LazyColumn(state = listState) {
        items(tiles) { tile ->
            tileViewModel.tileViewFactory.constructTileView(tile)
        }
    }

    listState.OnBottomReached(onEndReachedThreshold,  {
        loadMore()
    }, isLoading )
}
```

And here is where I render it

```
@Composable
fun Feed() {
    val feedViewModel: FeedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val tiles = feedViewModel.state.collectAsState()
    val isLoading = feedViewModel.isLoading.collectAsState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    TileListView(
        tiles = tiles.value,
        {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                feedViewModel.loadMore()
            }
        }, isLoading = isLoading.value, onEndReachedThreshold = 0
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, what does `isLoading` do inside `OnBottomReached`?

Comment: I don't see you using `isLoading` too. Also you can move logic from derived state into `snapshotFlow`, these two work under the same principles

Comment: Nah I resolved it. I think from where I use it I can easily control it. Idea was that if it is  already fetching data it does not fire two same requests. But now works fine when I move logic in correct place. @PylypDukhov can you maybe elaborate if have a time what you mean with move logic?!

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/f7a20e580dfc4f5ac9f8db59dc761d2e)

Comment: @PylypDukhov thx a lot. I must write that you are one best I see here. You always help and share knowledge. Often read your replies on other questions and I can just write kudos big man!

Comment: You're welcome. I see only one vote cast from your account - please upvote any answer that helps you, you can do it since you've reached 15 rating. I personally put an upvote for every answer from which I learned something, and for the question it was posted on, as without that there would be no answer. Voting is the most appropriate ways to thank someone on SO, see [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)